# How to find who has locked the files in Azure DevOps TFVC projects

Tags: security, devops, tfvc

I want to generate a report of the files being locked by other team members.
So far I have discovered that I can only view the files I have locked as a user.
I do have administration rights on this server/devops. So what are the **tf commands** that I can use to leverage the same?

I have reviewed this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-organization-collection-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), with no luck.